# Javascript On reload event

Tags: c#, javascript

I Have Javascript Function and I Want to call it On each time user Refresh the Page from Browser Not On page load or Body Onload
Can any one tel me the how to call the folowing function on Only reload from Browser in JS or C#

```
document.onkeydown = function disableKeys() {

    if( typeof event != 'undefined' ) {
      if( (event.keyCode == 112) ||
          (event.keyCode == 114) ||
          (event.keyCode == 116) ) {
        window.location.replace('Login.aspx');
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do you want the function to run before or after the page refreshes? Also, what do you mean by "call the following function" given that it is set up as an event handler? The user can refresh the page without using the keyboard, so then that function wouldn't do anything even if you did run it...

Comment: Yes Exactly when user Refresh the Page Without keyboard.Because My Above function is Working on F5 and Now I want that when user refresh the page then also redirect to login.aspx too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a direct way to do this, but you can do this:

It uses two diferent way of detecting refresh with JS
http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php

Comment: This Method Stoped working of My Above Function dnt working for my requirement